# Github push error. unable to read askpass & could not read Username

Tags: git, github, aptana

I am trying to push within Aptana but am getting the following error. I have successfully pulled, but can't figure out why my push won't work.

```
/home/jeni/apps/Aptana_Studio_3/plugins/com.aptana.git.core_3.0.0.1350339960/os/linux/askpass.    tcl: 3: exec: wish: not found
error: unable to read askpass response from     '/home/jeni/apps/Aptana_Studio_3/plugins/com.aptana.git.core_3.0.0.1350339960/os/linux/askpass.tcl'
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

Comment: I personally prefer to always work with SSH urls + my SSH key. Then there aren't issues when I change my GitHub password...

Comment: @jenia did you fixed?

Comment: This question is poorly written.  You should provide the steps that you took to configure Aptana.

Comment: This is happening with Android Studio for me right now. Aptana is Eclipse based while Android Studio is an IntelliJ. so I'm thinking this might be something Linux system-wise, like something with the default keyring is wrong.

Answer (score 20):

I solved the issue with "Credential Helper".
Navigate from Android Studio -> Preferences -> Version Control -> Git,
then tick the check box of "Credential Helper" -> Ok. Now, try to push again

Answer (score 13):

When this error occurs try `git push` from the terminal and you will be prompted a username and a password for your `git config` credentials and upon that a successful git push would happen

Comment: What should I do if credentials are not saved? If I try again username and password are asked again...

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same problem.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, Eclipse with Aptana plug-in. Through Aptana's Git I was having the same problem.

I solved it by installing TK and TCL packages. It then was able to read the askpass.tcl file.

```
sudo apt-get install tcl
sudo apt-get install tk
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Seborreia it woked for me in linux mint.

Answer (score 3):

The message "error: unable to read askpass response from '/tmp/git-askpass-0.sh'" was shown to me when I used Git from Intellij, but git worked fine from the terminal.

I tried Seborreia's method but it did not work

Someone suggested rebooting the computer.

Later on I realized that my jre/bin folder did not have appropriate permissions. Adding +x permissions fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error:

```
error: unable to read askpass response from...
```

I solved it by running:

```
unset SSH_ASKPASS
```

tried to pull again and everything works fine.

The solution is discussed here: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/git-login-issue-from-linux-command-line/qaq-p/716269

Comment: before this solution work you should check your environmental variables. `env | grep SSH_ASKPASS`

Comment: this fixed my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In my case just restarting machine did work.

Answer (score 0):

If this error message occurs when cloning Repository, then try to use the SSH url in the clone command instead of the HTTPS url (provided by your repo).

Of course assuming the following already done on your shell ( Git bash for my case ):

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"  # starts agent
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_githubPrivateKey  # add the key
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a conflict between Android Studio Git and manually installed Git.
So removing installed helped.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the same error was occurring because I was giving the wrong URL for the 'git clone' command.

I was incorrectly using the HTTPS url whereas I needed to use the SSH url which is of the format 'git clone git@github.company.net:HEAD/reponame.git'

Answer (score -1):

In Android Studio File -> Settings -> Git -> Credentials Helper(check this option)

If its not working even after checking 'Credentials helper' in settings then only restart the Android Studio and try to push code again.

Comment: This is literally a copy paste from the answer, shame on you